# CVE Security golang ubuntu 20.04

Tags: security, ubuntu-20.04, cve

Can anyone help me to find and update the package for **golang on ubuntu 20.04** ? After trivy image container scanner found some HIGH cve security but searching on the ubuntu I dont have these packages:

```
golang.org/x/text   │ CVE-2021-38561 │ HIGH     │        │ 0.3.0                             │ 0.3.7                      
golang.org/x/net    │ CVE-2019-9512  │ HIGH     │        │ 0.0.0-20190404232315-eb5bcb51f2a3 │ 0.0.0-20190813141303-74dc4d7220e7
golang.org/x/crypto │ CVE-2020-29652 │ HIGH     │ fixed  │ 0.0.0-20190308221718-c2843e01d9a2 │ 0.0.0-20201216223049-8b5274cf687f 




root@589417322bdb:/# apt-cache search golang.org/x/text
root@589417322bdb:/# 

root@589417322bdb:/# apt install golang.org/x/text
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package golang.org/x
```